# ACF как вывести метаданные рубрики?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, cms, acf

У меня на сайте Wordpress установлен плагин ACF. Я создал поля для рубрик и ввел туда данные. Теперь не знаю, как их вывести. У пост тайпов выводилось вот так:

```
get_field(metabox, $post->ID)
```

но с рубриками это не прокатило. В интернете много видел решений, но они мне почему-то не помогают.

P.S. Я хочу вывести с метабокса картинку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня работает так:

В ACF задал полю с картинкой "имя" `term_thumbnail`.

[image: скриншот админки ACF]

URL нужной картинки получаю так:

```
$term = get_term( $term_id );
$thumbnail = get_field( 'term_thumbnail', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term_id );
$thumbnail_url = $thumbnail['sizes']['thumbnail'];
```

Вот [инструкция в документации ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/) (на английском).

Comment: Спасибо! Выручили